# How to terminate the app when internet is not available android

Tags: android

I have been trying to terminate or close the app after it checks for internet, it proceeds when there is internet connection, if there is no internet connection it just terminates the activity and proceeds with the application, I have used functions like

```
finish();
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
super.finish();
moveTaskToBack(true);
MainActivity.this.finish();
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid()); didn't kill the app?

Comment: It's bad practice to terminate the app. Is there a specific reason you want to kill the app rather than just finish the main `Activity`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below snipped would check for connectivity and then finish the `Activity` if it's not available. I would advise against killing the process.

```
ConnectivityManager cm =
    (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                      activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

if (!isConnected) {
    finish();
}
```

There's additional docs [here](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing.html) for checking network. The second link will help you determine if the network becomes available again (which could be helpful if you decide to block the UI until they enable internet connection)

Comment: Thank you very much it worked. Very well I even toasted it to show some message.

Answer (score 0):

`finish()` will cause the current activity to close.
What you should do is finish all activities, then your app is closed

Answer (score 0):

When you ask something for the app to do just call onDestroy or **System.exit(0);**
this worked for me.